# why there's space on the top of my flask app

Tags: html, css, web, flask, styles

i'm an absolute beginner. I'm using flask to create a basic blog app. Can someone explain me why does it left so much space on the top of my flask app? I linked an image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eo9ic.png). before the space on the top appeared I added a style for my posts:
    `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/main.css">`

```
<article class="media content-section">
    <div class="media-body">
        <div class="article-metadata">
            <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ post.author }}</a>
            <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}</small>
        </div>
        <h2><a class="article-title" href="#">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
        <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
    </div>
</article>
```

the space disappear deleting the style link, so the problem may be in the css; This is main.css:

```
body {
  background: #fafafa;
  color: #333333;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  color: #444444;
}

.bg-steel {
  background-color: #5f788a;
}

.site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #cbd5db;
}

.site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
  font-weight: 500;
}


.content-section {
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.article-title {
  color: #444444;
}

a.article-title:hover {
  color: #428bca;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.article-content {
  white-space: pre-line;
}

.article-img {
  height: 65px;
  width: 65px;
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.article-metadata {
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e3
}

.article-metadata a:hover {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.article-svg {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

i also tried to modify the CSS but nothing seems to change. Please someone explain me where the problem is

Comment: You are adding margin to the body. `margin-top: 5rem;`. That is likely to be the reason.

Comment: `body {
  background: #fafafa;
  color: #333333;
  /* margin-top: 5rem; */
}`

delete `margin-top: 5rem`

Answer (score 0):

try removing  margin-top

```
body {
  background: #fafafa;
  color: #333333;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any test link?